# How to use ActiveRecord transactions on API call that saves multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have one API which accepts following data (objects) in 1 XML. The API converts this XML into respective objects and saves it in DB.

```
User
--> Location
--> Payment data

Order
--> Bill Item
```

I want to implement a Transaction of something like this

```
___.transaction do

User.create
--> Location.create
--> Payment.create

Order.create
--> Bill Item.create

end
```

Can Transactions be used in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do it inside ActiveRecord. Just raise an exception to rollback the transaction.

```
User.transaction do
  User.create
  Location.create
  Payment.create

  Order.create
  Bill Item.create
end
```

Check out for more details
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html.

Comment: Thank you Chamnap. Q - Would not the lock be released once User is created?

Comment: It's not about the lock. Database transaction simply means it gets saved all or none of them saved, (Atomicity).
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28database_systems%29